# Passing array of objects as observable from service to components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I am trying to pass message data from service into component as observable. In the component I want to subscribe the data. I tried many ways but it is not working.  How can I pass the array of objects as observable? I hope then it should work.

Currently I am getting an error in browser:

> TypeError: this.chatService.getMessages(...).subscribe is not a
>   function

**message.component.ts**

```
    import {
     Component,
     Input,
     OnInit,
     Output,
     EventEmitter,
     HostListener,
     ElementRef,
     Injectable
 } from "@angular/core";
 import {
     ChatService
 } from '../../service/chat.service';
 import * as sio from 'socket.io-client';
 import {
     Http,
     Headers,
     RequestOptions
 } from "@angular/http";
 import {
     Observable
 } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
 @Component({

     selector: "messages",
     templateUrl: './messages.component.html'

 })
 @Injectable()
 export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
     connection;

     ngOninit() {

         this.connection = this.chatService.getMessages().subscribe(message => {
                 console.log(message)
             }

this.chatService.createMqttConnection(this.userId);



         }


   sendMessage(data:Object){

     //let data = {'msg':message, '_receiverId':receiverId, '_senderId':senderId}

      this.http.post('/messages/sendmessage',data).map((res: any) => res.json()).subscribe((res: any) => {
        // console.log('###################')
        // console.log(res)
        // console.log('###################')
         this._client.subscribe("sendmessage");

            var msg =  new Paho.MQTT.Message(JSON.stringify(res));

          msg.destinationName = "sendmessage";

         this._client.send(msg);

      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
     );



   }

     }
```

**chat.service.ts**

```
    import {
     Subject
 } from 'rxjs/Subject';
 import {
     Observable
 } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import * as sio from 'socket.io-client';
 import {
     Injectable
 } from '@angular/core';
 import {
     Http,
     Headers,
     RequestOptions
 } from "@angular/http";
 import 'ng2-mqtt/mqttws31.js';

 declare
 var Paho: any;


 @Injectable()
 export class ChatService {
     private _client: any = "";
     public messageData: any = []; //--> [object, object]

     constructor(private http: Http) {

         this._client.onMessageArrived = (message: any) => {
             console.log('Message arrived.' + message);
             this.messageData.push(JSON.parse(message.payloadString));
             console.log(this.getMessages())
         };
     }



     getMessages() {

         return this.messageData;
     }
 }
```

**Solution:**

I solve it with the special type of observable "subject". I don't really understand why it doesn't work with Observable

I crated first an object

**chat.service.ts**

```
let printmessage = new Subject<any>(); 

this.printmessage.next(message);
```

**message.component.ts**

```
this.connection = this.chatService.printMessage.subscribe(message => {

console.log('Message: ' + message.message)
});
```

Comment: Move the code that's inside the constructor to the function get messages()

Comment: TypeError: Cannot create property 'onMessageArrived' on string ''

Comment: When messages are emitted is it a continues process or once

Comment: getMessages doesn't return an observable, why did you think you could or should subscribe to it?

Comment: @Aravind just once @ jonrsharpe yes, that is the question how can I return it as observable

Answer (score 1):

Your service should be like this (conceptually thinking):

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as sio from 'socket.io-client';
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import 'ng2-mqtt/mqttws31.js';

 declare let Paho: any;

 @Injectable()
 export class ChatService {
     private _client: any = "";
     public messageData: any = []; //--> [object, object]

     constructor(private http: Http) {

     }
     //Remember this will keep pushing items in your array as they arrive 
     //and keep returning messageData array
     getMessages():Observable<messageData> {
         this._client.onMessageArrived = (message: any) => {
             console.log('Message arrived.' + message);
             this.messageData.push(JSON.parse(message.payloadString));  
         };

        return this.messageData;
     }
 }
```

and then you dont need @Injectable() in your component. Here is how your constructor and ngOnInit should look like:

```
constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.connection = this.chatService.getMessages().subscribe(message => {
        //here message is the array                     
        console.log(message)
             }
     }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: /chat.service.ts (122,33): Cannot find name 'messageData'.) this error is occuring

Comment: Tony - before you downvote,  at least consider what I wrote in my post. I wrote the answer without any editor and I am pretty sure if you give it 5 minutes thought before executing as-is in an editor, you will make it work :) Looking at your error instead of Observable<messageData>, you need to say Observable<DataTypeOfMessageData>

Comment: yes I did but subscribing is not a function occuring as error... thanx

Answer (score 0):

chat-service.ts:

```
//import Observable:
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
...
...
...

getMessages() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        observer.next(this.messageData);
        observer.complete();
    });

}
```

Comment: this.connection = this.chatService.getMessages().subscribe(message => console.log('Message ' + message)); I am not getting any value. It is empty